# How to highlight the current month?

Tags: reactjs, momentjs

How to highlight the current month? Now I get an array with all the months, then display it, how to highlight the current month in the array?

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import moment from "moment";

export default function App() {
  const month = moment.months(); // Array
  const actualMonth = moment()
    .subtract("month")
    .startOf("month")
    .format("MMMM"); // String

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <span>{month}</span>
      <br />
      <span>
        Actual month: <b>{actualMonth}</b>
      </span>
    </div>
  );
}
```

To make it look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
<span>{month}</span>
```

map through each month, wrap it in a span, and if it's the `actualMonth`, add a class:

```
<span>
  {month.map(mo => {
    if (mo === actualMonth) {
      return (
        <span className="highlight">
          {mo}
        </span>
      );

    return (
      <span>
        {mo}
      </span>
    );
  })}
```